# Link Access to a SharePoint file whose name keeps changing

Tags: excel, url, script, vba

I have an Access database that I would like to link to an Excel file located on SharePoint. Normally, this is easy to accomplish as SharePoint/MS Office are well integrated.

The problem is, the Excel file in question is maintained by a contractor who uploads a different version each month, e.g., "inventory_jan", "inventory_feb", etc. -- which means that the URL/path of the latest data source is constantly changing.

Basically, I'm looking for some kind of automated solution that will retrieve the latest version of a file from a SharePoint document library where the file name is like *inventory_**

Comment: interesting question, did you find a solution in the meantime?